# How to change an array of strings into an array of integers in objC?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, casting, nsarray

I retrieved an array of NSString-Objects (`couples`) out of another dynamic array `valuesFirstdance`. I know that the strings always contain integers. I need the values to be of type integer to sort the `couples`array. How would I change to type of every array value?

Thanks

```
couples = [valuesFirstdance allKeys];
NSArray* couples2 = [couples sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(intValue)];
```

Comment: `valuesFirstdance` can't be an array; `allKeys` is an `NSDictionary` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question directly:

```
NSMutableArray *integerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:couples.count];
for (NSString *s in couples) {
   [integerArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:s.integerValue]];
}
```

But you could also do numeric sorting on the string values, e.g., using `NSNumericSearch`:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [couples sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *o1, NSString *o2) {
    return [o1 compare:o2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` has a method called `intValue` - that is what you're looking for.

Of course, a better solution would be to have an array of `NSNumber`s instead of `NSString`s.

You don't have to change the type of every array value to sort the couples array - look at this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [couplesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

NSString *firstString = (NSString*) obj1;
NSString *secondString = (NSString*) obj2;

if([firsString integerValue]<[secondString integerValue]) 
return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
else if([firsString integerValue]>[secondString integerValue])
return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;

return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;
                    }];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know about intValue and tried it with the sorting method, but I can't figure out how to use it there (if possible at all). As I do not know how many entries my `couples`array contains (from 3 up to 7), I'm not sure if your approach is what I'm looking for..

Comment: well have you tried the sorting code I provided in my answer?